# Do i have to malloc for each word?

Tags: c, while-loop, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am developing a software that use BST (Binary Search Tree), but i don't understand what's going on:

```
while (1)
{
    word = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * wordLength);

    readReturn = scanf("%s", word);
    if (readReturn == 0)
        return 0;
    BSTNode new = newBSTNode(word);
    if (strcmp(word, "END") == 0)
        break;
    TreeInsert(Tree, new);
}
```

In this way the program it's working and give the input "aaa" "bbb", the tree has the right value. But if i declare the variable outside the program stop working and the output is:
"bbb" "bbb".

```
     word = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * wordLength);    
     while (1)
     {
        readReturn = scanf("%s", word);

        if (readReturn == 0)
            return 0;
        BSTNode new = newBSTNode(word);
        if (strcmp(word, "END") == 0)
            break;
        TreeInsert(Tree, new);
     }
```

Please, explain me why this is happening!

Comment: Your question title is completely different than your question. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question.

Comment: Basically, you're re-using the same area of memory for all the nodes in the second case.

Comment: My ***guess*** is that `newBSTNode` copies the *pointer* and not the string contents.

Comment: You leave a dangling pointer and a memory leak in the "it works" case. Also `if (readReturn == 0)` should be `if (readReturn != 1)`

Comment: On a different note, you should probably check for `"END"` before you create the node. And remember to `free` the memory you allocate.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: In response to title: If you want to store different words, then each word needs its own place in memory... Yes, you have to malloc for each word (or use your own "object pool" that you maintain...) BTW: I don't see any check that the entered "word" does not overflow the allocated buffer... Hmmm.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second code snippet

```
 word = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * wordLength);    
 while (1)
 {
    readReturn = scanf("%s", word);

    if (readReturn == 0)
        return 0;
    BSTNode new = newBSTNode(word);
    if (strcmp(word, "END") == 0)
        break;
    TreeInsert(Tree, new);
 }
```

all strings are stored in the same dynamically allocated extent of memory that was allocated once before the while loop.

```
 word = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * wordLength);
```

So all nodes refer to it and what was stored last in this extent is outputted for all nodes.

Pay attention to that in the first code snippet

```
while (1)
{
    word = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * wordLength);

    readReturn = scanf("%s", word);
    if (readReturn == 0)
        return 0;
    BSTNode new = newBSTNode(word);
    if (strcmp(word, "END") == 0)
        break;
    TreeInsert(Tree, new);
}
```

there can be a memory leak if after the loop there is no statement

```
free( word );
```